# C++ low latency websocket without asio

Tags: c++, websocket, low-latency

I’m looking to write some low latency hft c++ software and would like to avoid using boost asio (planning on using linen for my event loop).

Is there a c++ websocket library that will support this ?

Comment: https://github.com/Anisbelaid/HFT-exchange I have worked on that , there are bench of low latency servers socket (binary protocol)  used no websocket sorry , you need to fix some bugs but I think it is a good starts

Comment: what are your requirements for this library? did you try googling "C++ websocket library"?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks Anis Belaid ! I'll take a look
I did have a look Alan Birtles. Most C++ websocket libs I've found are dependent on asio and I'd rather re-invent the wheel if I dont have to

Comment: @David Co try to use POCO websocket they are easier to use